# Problems in migrating from swagger_jaxrs_2.10 to latest swagger_jaxrs

Tags: java, tomcat, swagger, swagger-2.0

I had swagger_jaxrs_2.10 (1.3.6) working for a long time, I want to benefit from the new 2.0 swagger specification.

Hence I've changed in my pom from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run, I get the following error trying to access `myApp/swagger.json`

```
SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates. The URI template / for root resource class io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource and the URI template / transform to the same regular expression (/.*)?
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd strongly advise reading https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/1.3--1.5-Migration - keep in mind you're not migrating to the latest version.

Comment: is there a jaxrs version that is the newer? I couldn't find its maven dependency, can you point me to it.

Comment: thx. Now I see I need to use a new groupId io.swagger. Will check it!

Comment: @Ron I've done the needed steps in the migration. same result. I've updated the question

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/1.3--1.5-Migration#structure-and-hosting is crucial to your question.

Comment: @Ron yes, I tried that... same problem when accessing swagger.json

Comment: (I just forgot to update the question... now updated)

Comment: Do you have any resource exposed directly on "/?? can you share your web.xml? (fwiw, these kind of questions would be better handled in our google group. SO is not built for a back'n'forth communication)

Comment: moved the discussion to Swagger google group. Hopefully in the right place. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/VOSKCMP3mbU
this includes the web.xml definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of swagger from the 1.5.x libraries, the swagger description will live at `/swagger.json`.  It depends on where your app is mounted though.

The error message your describing tells me that you're mounting a root resource (`/*`) which is indeed going to conflict with the `/swagger.json`.  Consider mounting your API on a path like `/users` or something else to avoid that conflict.